# How can I write a parquet file using Spark (pyspark)?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm pretty new in Spark and I've been trying to convert a Dataframe to a parquet file in Spark but I haven't had success yet. The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) says that I can use **write.parquet** function to create the file. However, when I run the script it shows me: *AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'write'*

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Protob Conversion to Parquet ")

# spark is an existing SparkSession
df = sc.textFile("/temp/proto_temp.csv")

# Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.write.parquet("/output/proto.parquet")
```

Do you know how to make this work?

The spark version that I'm using is Spark 2.0.1 built for Hadoop 2.7.3.

Comment: `sc.textFile()` returns `RDD`.

Comment: Yes, I just realised it. I just changed to SparkSession instead of SparkContext

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The error was due to the fact that the `textFile` method from `SparkContext` returned an `RDD` and what I needed was a `DataFrame`.

SparkSession has a `SQLContext` under the hood. So I needed to use the `DataFrameReader` to read the CSV file correctly before converting it to a parquet file.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Protob Conversion to Parquet") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

# read csv
df = spark.read.csv("/temp/proto_temp.csv")

# Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.show()

df.write.parquet("output/proto.parquet")
```

Comment: Even if your code is correct, your explanation isn't. SparkContext doesn't convert the CSV file to an RDD. The `textFile` method from SparkContext returns an RDD and what you need is a `DataFrame` thus a SQLContext or a HiveContext which is also encapsulated in a SparkSession in **spark 2+** Would you care correcting that information and accept the answer to close the question ?

Comment: Thanks @eliasah for your feedback!

Comment: The answer is for dataframe. how can i write an rdd in parquet format?

Comment: df.write.parquet takes the file folder as an argument and not its absolute path.

Comment: @eliasah Does your comment mean that for **spark 2+** we need only the following two lines to convert csv to Parquet: `df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/infile.csv")
df.write.csv("/path/to/outfile.parquet"` Did I get it right?

Answer (score 7):

You can also write out Parquet files from Spark with [koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas).  This library is great for folks that prefer Pandas syntax.  Koalas is PySpark under the hood.

Here's the Koala code:

```
import databricks.koalas as ks

df = ks.read_csv('/temp/proto_temp.csv')
df.to_parquet('output/proto.parquet')
```

Comment: Hi @Powers, I tried installing it

`sc.install_pypi_package("koalas") #Install latest koalas version` 

while I was working on AWS EMR. However, when I tried importing it it said `No module named 'koalas'`

Comment: @Sowmya - This link explains how to install pypi packages in an EMR environment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-install-kernels-libs.html. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. That's indeed nice of you to reply to my comment. I knew that link, just instead of doing a system installation, was thinking of more of a local or noteboook specific installation. Well, if the local one doesn't work out then would go for system installation.