# Convert csv to parquet file using python

Tags: python, csv, parquet

I am trying to convert a .csv file to a .parquet file.
The csv file (`Temp.csv`) has the following format

```
1,Jon,Doe,Denver
```

I am using the following python code to convert it into parquet

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="CSV2Parquet")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    schema = StructType([
            StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
            StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
            StructField("col4", StringType(), True)])
    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname,'Temp.csv')    
    rdd = sc.textFile(csvfilename).map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
    parquetfilename = os.path.join(dirname,'output.parquet')    
    df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(parquetfilename)
```

The result is only a folder named, `output.parquet` and not a parquet file that I'm looking for, followed by the following error on the console.

[image: CSV to Parquet Error]

I have also tried running the following code to face a similar issue.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Protob Conversion to Parquet") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

# read csv
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname,'Temp.csv')    
df = spark.read.csv(csvfilename)

# Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.show()
parquetfilename = os.path.join(dirname,'output.parquet')    
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(parquetfilename)
```

How to best do it? Using windows, python 2.7.

Comment: [Similar question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022890/how-can-i-write-a-parquet-file-using-spark-pyspark)

Comment: @lwileczek It's a different question as the linked question explicitly asks for Spark, this is just about using Python in general.

Answer (score 70):

Using the packages `pyarrow` and `pandas` you can convert CSVs to Parquet without using a JVM in the background:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df.to_parquet('output.parquet')
```

One limitation in which you will run is that `pyarrow` is only available for Python 3.5+ on Windows. Either use Linux/OSX to run the code as Python 2 or upgrade your windows setup to Python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there a way to do it using Python 2.7 on Windows?

Comment: This is a very simple way to convert a single file into a parquet file, but what if we have multiple csv files and we want to par it into a single parquet file?

Comment: @Zombraz you could loop through the files and convert each to parquet,
if you are looking for anything outside of python, hive on AWS EMR works great in converting csv to parquet

Comment: @Zombraz - you can use Dask or PySpark to convert multiple CSV files to a single Parquet file (or multiple Parquet files).  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 35):

You can convert csv to parquet using pyarrow only - without pandas.
It might be useful when you need to minimize your code dependencies (ex. with AWS Lambda).

```
import pyarrow.csv as pv
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pv.read_csv(filename)
pq.write_table(table, filename.replace('csv', 'parquet'))
```

Refer to the pyarrow docs to fine-tune [`read_csv`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.read_csv.html) and [`write_table`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html) functions.

Answer (score 15):

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from s3fs import S3FileSystem
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

s3 = boto3.client('s3',region_name='us-east-2')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='ssiworkoutput', Key='file_Folder/File_Name.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

output_file = "s3://ssiworkoutput/file/output.parquet"  # S3 Path need to mention
s3 = S3FileSystem()

pq.write_to_dataset(table=table,
                    root_path=output_file,partition_cols=['Year','Month'],
                    filesystem=s3)

print("File converted from CSV to parquet completed")
```

Comment: This is code for reading CSV file from AWS S3 path store it with Parquet format with partition in AWS S3 path.

Comment: Make sure to run the below,
pip3 install boto3
pip3 install pandas
pip3 install pyarrow
pip3 install fs-s3fs
pip3 install s3fs

Comment: How did you install pyarrow without having package's size problem on aws?

Comment: @Haha The easiest way is using [awswrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/releases) layer which already includes pyarrow

Answer (score 12):

There are a few different ways to convert a CSV file to Parquet with Python.

Uwe L. Korn's Pandas approach works perfectly well.

Use Dask if you'd like to convert multiple CSV files to multiple Parquet / a single Parquet file.  This will convert multiple CSV files into two Parquet files:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('./data/people/*.csv')
df = df.repartition(npartitions=4)
df.to_parquet('./tmp/people_parquet4')
```

You could also use `df.repartition(npartitions=1)` if you'd only like to output one Parquet file.  More info on converting CSVs to Parquet with Dask [here](https://mungingdata.com/dask/read-csv-to-parquet/).

Here's a PySpark snippet that works in a Spark environment:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .master("local") \
  .appName("parquet_example") \
  .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv('data/us_presidents.csv', header = True)
df.repartition(1).write.mode('overwrite').parquet('tmp/pyspark_us_presidents')
```

You can also use [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas) in a Spark environment:

```py
import databricks.koalas as ks

df = ks.read_csv('data/us_presidents.csv')
df.to_parquet('tmp/koala_us_presidents')
```

Answer (score 8):

**Handling larger than memory CSV files**

Below code converts CSV to Parquet without loading the  whole csv file into the memory

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

new_schema = pa.schema([
    ('col1', pa.int64()),
    ('col2', pa.int64()),
    ('newcol', pa.int64())
])

csv_column_list = ['col1', 'col2']

with pq.ParquetWriter('my_parq_data.parquet', schema=new_schema) as writer:
    with pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', header=None, names=csv_column_list, chunksize=100000) as reader:
        for df in reader:
            # transformation: transform df by adding a new static column with column name 'newcol' and value 9999999
            df['newcol'] = 9999999
            # convert pandas df to record batch
            transformed_batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_pandas(df, schema=new_schema)
            writer.write_batch(transformed_batch)
```

Above code:

1. Reads the large [CSV file in chunks](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
2. Transforms the data frame by adding the new column.
3. Converts the df to [arrow record batch](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.RecordBatch.html?highlight=recordbatch#pyarrow.RecordBatch.from_pandas).
4. Writes the transformed arrow batch as a [new row group](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.write_table) to the parquet file.

**Note**: Do not keep the chunk size very low. This will result in poor compression since chunk size corresponds to the row group size in the new parquet file as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can write as a PARQUET FILE using **spark**:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test_Parquet").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

parquetDF = spark.read.csv("data.csv")

parquetDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("Parquet")
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import sys

sc = SparkContext(appName="CSV2Parquet")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col3", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col4", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col5", StringType(), True)])
rdd = sc.textFile('/input.csv').map(lambda line: line.split(","))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.write.parquet('/output.parquet')
```

Comment: Please add some explanations why this answers the question.

Comment: convert csv to parquet using pyspark , this is working for me, hope it helps

Comment: This approach works but is several times slower than using the spark csv reader

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pyspark library to convert a CSV file to a Parquet file. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
rc = spark.read.csv('/path/file.csv', header=True)
rc.write.format("parquet").save('/path/file.parquet')
```

This code reads a CSV file and the convert it to a Parquet file.

Answer (score 0):

it helps for me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', low_memory=False)
df.to_parquet('output.parquet', engine="fastparquet")
```

Comment: Just to mention that pandas .read_csv can be really slow on large files.  If you are impatient, use a faster loader eg. pyarrow, fastparquet to read the .csv and then to export it as .parquet

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pyarrow.csv as csv

dataframe = csv.read_csv("file.csv")



pyarrow.parquet.write_table(dataframe,"dataframe.parquet")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?