# Converting a very very large csv to parquet

Tags: python, csv, parquet

I am trying to convert a csv file to parquet (I don't really care if it is done in python or command line, or...) In any case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604133/convert-csv-to-parquet-file-using-python) addresses is, but the answers seem to require one to read the csv in first, and since in my case the csv is 17GB, this is not really feasible, so I would like some "offline" or streaming approach.

Comment: Yes. I have CSVs approaching 300GB I need to convert.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully converted a 7GB+ (2.7 millions lines) CSV file into a parquet file, using [csv2parquet](https://github.com/domoritz/csv2parquet).

The process is simple:

- First I had to clean my CSV with [csvclean](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvclean.html) from csvkit (but you might not need this)
- Generate a JSON schema with csv2parquet
- Edit the schema by hand, as it might not suit you
- Generate the parquet file thanks to csv2parquet
- Bonus: use DuckDB to test simple SQL queries directly on the parquet file

You can probably reproduce the process if you download our CSV export at https://world.openfoodfacts.org/data

```bash
# Not needed for you, just in case you want to reproduce
wget https://static.openfoodfacts.org/data/en.openfoodfacts.org.products.csv
csvclean -t en.openfoodfacts.org.products.csv

# Generate the schema
./csv2parquet --header true -p -n en.openfoodfacts.org.products_out.csv products_zstd.pqt > parquet.shema
# It has to be modified because column detection is sometimes wrong.
# From Open Food Facts CSV, for example, the code column is detected as a an Int64, but it's in fact a "Utf8".
nano parquet.shema

# Generate parquet file.
# Using -c for compression is optional.
# -c zstd appears to be the best option regarding speed/compression.
./csv2parquet --header true -c zstd -s parquet.schema en.openfoodfacts.org.products_out.csv products_zstd.pqt

# Try a query thanks to DuckDB. It's as fast as a database!
time ./duckdb test-duck.db "select * FROM (select count(data_quality_errors_tags) as products_with_issues from read_parquet('products_zstd.pqt') where data_quality_errors_tags != ''), (select count(data_quality_errors_tags) as products_with_issues_but_without_images from $db where data_quality_errors_tags != '' and last_image_datetime == '');"
┌──────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ products_with_issues │ products_with_issues_but_without_images │
├──────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 29333                │ 4897                                    │
└──────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────┘

real    0m0,211s
user    0m0,645s
sys 0m0,053s
```