# Do I need to put a file in a panda's dataframe to put in parquet format?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, parquet

I am new to using spark and it seems like we have to put a file in pandas format in order to put it in parquet format. Is that right? Are there ways we could directly put them in parquet format.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't. Spark dataframes are not the same as pandas dataframes. That said, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42023495/2412831) is probably what you are looking for. There is also plenty of information on the matter in the official Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html).